# Multiple Picker view in Expandable Tableview Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, tableview

I want to make expandable tableview, I am using this example to create expandable tableview http://www.appcoda.com/expandable-table-view/

My problem is when i want to create custom tableviewcell class and picker view datasource method then all tableview cell which contains picker view have same values not different , what can do to set different value for all tableview cell picker view

here is code

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell,UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var picker: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var detailLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var mainLabel: UILabel!
var picArr = [String]()
var dic : NSMutableDictionary!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    dic = NSMutableDictionary()
    dic = ["item1":"Height,Width","item2":"Feet,Centimeter"]

    picArr = ["Pounds","Kilograms","Stone"]

}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

// PickerView Datasource

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    print(component)
    return picArr.count
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

    return picArr[row]
}
```

}

Comment: you have fixed value of array so it is displaying fix vaue

Answer (score 0):

Your every cell is displaying static array of data `picArr = ["Pounds","Kilograms","Stone"]`. If you want different value for different picker then first you required different arrays to display it or array of arrays. And you have to wrote logic accordingly

You can write this all scenario in `cellforrowatindexpath` also.

**Update :**

refer [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28966278/pickerview-load-up-tableview-data-swift) for more details.

Hope this will help :)